# SonarQube deprecated rule suggestion missing

Tags: sonarqube

In SonarCube 6.7.5, rule squid:S2077 (SQL binding mechanisms should be used) is depreciated.   The replacement rule is listed as S3649  (/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AS3649).  That link is not resolving to an actual rule.

How do I get this issue resolved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The rule has been deprecated and the replacement (S3649) is available only in:

- paid versions (example: Developer Edition)
- server 7.X or newer

Read more here:

- [S2077 has been deprecated but documentation doesn't include a justification](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/s2077-has-been-deprecated-but-documentation-doesnt-include-a-justification/1688?u=agabrys)
- [Deprecated rule squid:S2077 still on Sonar way and causing false positives](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/deprecated-rule-squid-s2077-still-on-sonar-way-and-causing-false-positives/2139?u=agabrys)
- [Rule S3649 Not Found Enterprise Edition Version 6.7.5](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/rule-s3649-not-found-enterprise-edition-version-6-7-5/3035?u=agabrys)

Comment: We are running the Enterprise Edition.  Is there something special we need to be doing to make this rule show up?

Comment: You should ask [here](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/s2077-has-been-deprecated-but-documentation-doesnt-include-a-justification/1688?u=agabrys), I think that Ann will answer the question.